# How to receive an object in REST java angular?

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, angular6

A map with variables & two strings must be sent from front end to backend. Map can have multiple entries each time. How to achieve this?

Current result of the code:

[image: Current result of the code]

sample.component.ts

```
// construct variable map
const varMap = new Map<string, string>();
const variableMap = {};
varMap.forEach((val: string, key: string) => {
variableMap[key] = val;});

// send map to service
this.exampleService.mySendFunc(variabeMap).subscribe();
```

sample.service.ts

```
   mySendFunc(variables: any): Observable<any> {
        const aaa = {
            'testId1': testId1,
            'testId2': testId2
        };
        return this.http.post(this.URL, {variables, aaa});
    }
```

sample.java

```
@PostMapping("/example")
public void completeTask(@RequestBody Object variables, Object aaa) {
   // breakpoint hire
}
```

Comment: you can directly receive as Map. `@RequestBody Map<String,Object> variables`

Answer (score 0):

You can post only one request object at a time. Set related Id property to a path variable.

JS

```
this.http.post(this.URL + '/' + testId, {varMap});
```

JAVA

```
@PostMapping("/example/{testId}")
public void completeTask(
   @RequestBody Map<String, String> varMap,
   @PathVariable String testId) {
// ...
}
```

Comment: Can I have two Path variables that point to the same `@PostMapping("/example")`  like `@PathVariable String testId1, String testId2` at the same time? So 2 variables & 1 map ?

Comment: That's a bit weird, but you can have @PostMapping("/example/{testId1}/{testId2}"). In most cases you should provide only one identifying parameter at a time.

Comment: Im trying to send a following object to backend basically, so I an looking for possible options. Your example looks weird indeed, that is why I was asking if there was a nice way. Object: `public class Example {
    Long caseId;
    String taskId;
    String processId;
    Map<String, Object> variabes;
}`